# Meeting invitation triggers out of office from unrelated person

Tags: outlook-2007, email

I just got a mail from someone notifying me of an out of office reply she received after she sent a meeting request to 3 different people, not including the one that's on leave.

She said my colleague (who is out of the office himself and who I won't bother for unimportant things) knew about this in the past, but I'm not sure what it could be.

The only thing I can think of is shared calendars of some sort.

Does anyone have an idea?
Br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit rusty on Exchange 2007 admin so forgive me if I'm a bit vague:

This often happens if someone's mail account is set to forward all of their mail to a third party.

Check each mail account for forwarding rules on the server and client.

I believe it's also possible to delegate meeting room managers, who will receive meeting invites if the rooms they 'own' are booked. You may also want to check to see if a resource was booked and if so, whether anyone is setup to manage that resource.

Comment: +1 - Yep, your right with this! First place to check is email forwarding and then the second would be to check delegation settings for that user as another user can be set to arrange/accept meeting requests.